# Communities accepted topic information availability

Tags: feature-request, help-center

To decide whether to join a community or not, one could expect the definition of the accepted topics of the community to be easily available. But besides the one-sentence-long description found in the communities menu, the only way to get the information is to go:
Click `help` > `help center`
Then find and click the link 'What topics can I ask about here?`

So I'm asking for the following changes to be made to the site's template:
   1) Make the link to the "accepted topic" page of a community, directly accessible from it's welcome page
   2) Include more informations about the accepted topics on the welcome page.

Either that or explaining me why I'm wrong.

Comment: Why did you not look at the first option in that menu?

Comment: The description available on the /tour page is the same as the one of the communities menu.